# How do I clear Notifications when I open the app manually and they are not tapped?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I managed to make a Firebase cloud function to send me notifications of the latest chat msg. Everything works well.

The notifications arrive when the app is in the background or never started but I can still receive it while the app is in the foreground just fine.

Working fine:

- Tap on the notification to open App and dismiss the notification.
- Slide to dismiss the notification.

The Problem:

- Manually opening the app does not dismiss the notification.

Idea:

- On App Resume or Launch could I clear the notification or all notifications of the same Subscription? I have not found any examples to do this via Flutter but only on Android.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25030

Comment: do you know how to apply the solution to the Flutter app? I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: As mentioned in the github repository, you need to place that code in your MainActivity.java file which will be in the android folder of your project.

Comment: yeah I did that... there was no MainActivity.java on my project so I manually added one in this path Android/App/src/MainActivity.java and pasted the code but it still didn't work.

Comment: There should be one by default, is there MainActivity.kt file ? If yes, add the code to that. When you paste the java code it will ask for auto-converting to kotlin, accept that.

Comment: when I try to convert it says there are errors in protected void and private void (illegal type)

Answer (score 2):

Write something like in `MainActivity.kt` this if you use Kotlin:

```
package com.posignal.app

import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        closeAllNotifications();
    }

    private fun closeAllNotifications() {
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancelAll()
    }

}
```